# Migrate from one user pool to another user pool?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I deployed a user pool in Cognito which now needs additional custom attributes. These can't be added after the fact. Is it possible to now move those users from the old user pool to a new user pool? I saw mention of using a Lambda to do this, but seems like a fairly common case and Lambda seems unnecessarily complicated when you just want to export/re-import user data especially between user pools in the same AWS account.

Comment: Why can you not add custom attributes to your original user pool? If you want to migrate users from one pool to another you can export users as csv and then import the csv to new pool but this doesn't import passwords and your users will have to reset their passwords the first time they log in

Comment: Most of my users are authenticated using federated sign in. Also, I didn't see a "csv export" anywhere... can you point me to that in the console or is that an API only feature?

Comment: sadly there is no official way to export users. You can use cli to do it though. Make sure you use pagination if you have a lot of users. https://gist.github.com/chrisdiana/cc7464d0624885dace587b08ced052e4